# Dash app prevent auto refresh when switching between tabs

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Is there any way to prevent auto-refresh when switching between tabs? 
I have multiple tabs in my dash app and when I select any item from tab1 and then select tab2, and then get back to tab 1 all the selected items lost.

**Here is my index.py**

```
import base64

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from Dash_App.app import app
from Dash_App.tabs import facebook, googleanalytics, DCM, DV360

tabs_styles = {
    'height': '44px'
}
tab_style = {
    'borderBottom': '1px solid #d6d6d6',
    'padding': '6px',
    'fontWeight': 'bold'
}

tab_selected_style = {
    'borderTop': '1px solid #d6d6d6',
    'borderBottom': '1px solid #d6d6d6',
    'backgroundColor': '#119DFF',
    'color': 'white',
    'padding': '6px'
}

image_filename = 'Screenshot_3.png'
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open(image_filename, 'rb').read())

app.layout = html.Div([html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode()),
                                style={'height': '10%', 'width': '10%'}, ),
                       html.H6('Marketing Funnel Reports', style={'color': '#ffd480', 'font-weight': 'bold',
                                                                  'text-align': 'right', 'margin-top': -40}),
                       dcc.Tabs(id="tabs-example", value='tab-1-example',
                                children=[dcc.Tab(label='Facebook', value='tab-1-example',
                                                  style=tab_style, selected_style=tab_selected_style),
                                          dcc.Tab(label='GoogleAnalytics', value='tab-2-example',
                                                  style=tab_style, selected_style=tab_selected_style),
                                          dcc.Tab(label='DCM', value='tab-3-example', style=tab_style,
                                                  selected_style=tab_selected_style),
                                          dcc.Tab(label='DV360', value='tab-4-example', style=tab_style,
                                                  selected_style=tab_selected_style),
                                          ],
                                style=tabs_styles),
                       html.Div(id='tabs-content-example')])


@app.callback(Output('tabs-content-example', 'children'),
              [Input('tabs-example', 'value')])
def render_content(tab):
    if tab == 'tab-1-example':
        return facebook.tab_1_layout
    elif tab == 'tab-2-example':
        return googleanalytics.tab_2_layout
    elif tab == 'tab-3-example':
        return DCM.tab_3_layout
    elif tab == 'tab-4-example':
        return DV360.tab_4_layout
    else:
        return '404'


external_css = ["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css",
                "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css",
                "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600",
                "https://codepen.io/bcd/pen/KQrXdb.css",
                "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css",
                "https://codepen.io/dmcomfort/pen/JzdzEZ.css"]

for css in external_css:
    app.css.append_css({"external_url": css})

external_js = ["https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
               "https://codepen.io/bcd/pen/YaXojL.js"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**Here is my tab1.py**

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import datetime
import dash_table

from Dash_App.app import app
import pandas as pd

from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.user import User
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount

row1 = html.Div(
    [dcc.Store(id='local', storage_type='local'),
     dbc.Row([
         dbc.Col([
             dbc.Input(id="ad_account_id",
                       type="text",
                       placeholder="Account ID",
                       style={'width': '150px'}),
         ]),

         dbc.Col([
             dbc.Input(id="app_id",
                       type="text",
                       placeholder="App ID",
                       style={'width': '150px'}),
         ]),
         dbc.Col([
             dbc.Input(id="access_token",
                       type="text",
                       style={'width': '150px'},
                       placeholder="Access Token")
         ]),
         dbc.Col([
             dbc.Input(id="app_secret",
                       type="text",
                       style={'width': '150px'},
                       placeholder="App Secret")
         ]),

         dbc.Col([
             dcc.Dropdown(
                 id='metrics',
                 options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['account_currency',
                                                             'account_id',
                                                             'account_name',
                                                             'actions',
                                                             'ad_id',
                                                             'ad_name',
                                                             'adset_id',
                                                             'adset_name',
                                                             'buying_type',
                                                             'campaign_id',
                                                             'campaign_name',
                                                             'date_start',
                                                             'date_stop',
                                                             'objective',
                                                             'action_values',
                                                             'canvas_avg_view_percent',
                                                             'canvas_avg_view_time',
                                                             'clicks',
                                                             'conversion_rate_ranking',
                                                             'conversion_values',
                                                             'conversions',
                                                             'cost_per_action_type',
                                                             'cost_per_conversion',
                                                             'cost_per_estimated_ad_recallers',
                                                             'cost_per_inline_link_click',
                                                             'cost_per_inline_post_engagement',
                                                             'cost_per_outbound_click',
                                                             'cost_per_thruplay',
                                                             'cost_per_unique_action_type',
                                                             'cost_per_unique_click',
                                                             'cost_per_unique_inline_link_click',
                                                             'cost_per_unique_outbound_click',
                                                             'cpc', 'cpm', 'cpp', 'ctr',
                                                             'engagement_rate_ranking',
                                                             'estimated_ad_recall_rate',
                                                             'estimated_ad_recallers',
                                                             'frequency',
                                                             'full_view_impressions',
                                                             'full_view_reach', 'impressions',
                                                             'inline_link_click_ctr',
                                                             'inline_link_clicks',
                                                             'inline_post_engagement',
                                                             'instant_experience_clicks_to_open',
                                                             'instant_experience_clicks_to_start',
                                                             'instant_experience_outbound_clicks',
                                                             'mobile_app_purchase_roas',
                                                             'outbound_clicks',
                                                             'outbound_clicks_ctr',
                                                             'purchase_roas',
                                                             'quality_ranking',
                                                             'reach', 'social_spend',
                                                             'spend', 'unique_actions',
                                                             'unique_clicks', 'unique_ctr',
                                                             'unique_inline_link_click_ctr',
                                                             'unique_inline_link_clicks',
                                                             'unique_link_clicks_ctr',
                                                             'unique_outbound_clicks',
                                                             'unique_outbound_clicks_ctr',
                                                             'video_30_sec_watched_actions',
                                                             'video_avg_time_watched_actions',
                                                             'video_p100_watched_actions',
                                                             'video_p25_watched_actions',
                                                             'video_p50_watched_actions',
                                                             'video_p75_watched_actions',
                                                             'video_p95_watched_actions',
                                                             'video_play_actions',
                                                             'video_play_curve_actions',
                                                             'website_ctr',
                                                             'website_purchase_roas']],
                 multi=True,
                 style={'width': '300px'},
                 placeholder='Dimensions & Metrics')
         ]),
     ], align="center"),
     ], style={'margin-top': 20, 'margin-left': -90}
)

row2 = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='breakdown',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['ad_format_asset', 'age', 'body_asset',
                                                            'call_to_action_asset', 'country',
                                                            'description_asset',
                                                            'gender', 'image_asset',
                                                            'impression_device',
                                                            'link_url_asset',
                                                            'product_id',
                                                            'region',
                                                            'title_asset',
                                                            'video_asset',
                                                            'dma',
                                                            'frequency_value',
                                                            'hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone',
                                                            'hourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone',
                                                            'place_page_id',
                                                            'publisher_platform',
                                                            'platform_position',
                                                            'device_platform']],
                multi=True,
                style={'width': '250px'},
                placeholder='Breakdown')
        ]),
        html.Br(),
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                id='start-date',
                placeholder="Start Date",
                min_date_allowed=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('2018-01-01'),
                max_date_allowed=datetime.datetime.today().date(),
                display_format='YYYY-MM-DD',
                style={'width': '150px', 'margin-left': 30}
            ),
        ]),
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                id='end-date',
                placeholder="End Date",
                min_date_allowed=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('2018-01-01'),
                max_date_allowed=datetime.datetime.today().date(),
                display_format='YYYY-MM-DD',
                style={'width': '150px', 'margin-left': 40}
            )]),
    ])
])

row3 = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.Button(id='submit-button', type='submit', children='Submit', style={'width': '150px', 'margin-top': 5,
                                                                                     'margin-left': 370}),

        ], width={"order": "first"}),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(id='output_div'),
        ])
    ])
])

tab_1_layout = dbc.Container(children=[
    row1,
    html.Br(),
    row2,
    html.Br(),
    row3,
    html.Br(),
]
)


@app.callback(Output('output_div', 'children'),
              [Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks')],
              [State('ad_account_id', 'value'),
               State('app_id', 'value'), State('access_token', 'value'),
               State('app_secret', 'value'),
               State('metrics', 'value'),
               State('breakdown', 'value'),
               State('start-date', 'date'),
               State('end-date', 'date'),
               ],
              )
def facebook_output(clicks, ad_account_id, app_id, access_token, app_secret, metrics, breakdown,
                    start_date, end_date):
    if clicks is not None:
        my_ad_account = ad_account_id
        my_app_id = app_id
        my_access_token = access_token
        my_app_secret = app_secret
        my_metrics = metrics
        my_breakdown = breakdown
        my_start_date = start_date
        my_end_date = end_date
        my_action_type = 'action_type'
        my_level = 'ad'
        my_time_increment = 1
        FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token, api_version='v5.0')
        me = User(fbid="me")
        new_col_list = my_metrics
        print(new_col_list)
        act = AdAccount(my_ad_account)
        async_job = act.get_insights(params={'time_range': {'since': my_start_date, 'until': my_end_date},
                                             'breakdowns': list(my_breakdown),
                                             'action_breakdowns': my_action_type, 'level': my_level,
                                             'time_increment': my_time_increment},
                                     fields=list(new_col_list))
        df = pd.DataFrame(async_job)
        dff = df[new_col_list]
        html.Br()
        return html.Div([
            dash_table.DataTable(
                css=[{'selector': '.row',
                      'rule': 'margin: 0; white-space: inherit; overflow: inherit; text-overflow: inherit;'}],
                id='table',
                columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in dff.columns],
                data=dff.to_dict("rows"),
                export_format="csv",
                style_cell={"fontFamily": "Arial", "size": 10, 'textAlign': 'left',
                            'width': '{}%'.format(len(dff.columns)), 'textOverflow': 'ellipsis', 'overflow': 'hidden'},

                style_table={'maxHeight': '200px', 'overflowY': 'scroll', 'maxWidth': '1000px', 'overflowX': 'scroll'},
                style_header={'backgroundColor': '#ffd480', 'color': 'white', 'height': '10', 'width': '10',
                              'fontWeight': 'bold'},
                style_data={'whiteSpace': 'auto', 'height': 'auto', 'width': 'auto'},
                tooltip_data=[
                    {
                        column: {'value': str(value), 'type': 'markdown'}
                        for column, value in row.items()
                    } for row in dff.to_dict('rows')
                ],
                tooltip_duration=None
            ),
        ], style={'margin-top': 60, 'display': 'inline-block', 'margin-left': -250, 'width': '100%'})
```

same as tab1 I have tab 2.

Comment: I just solved this by passing persistence in the layout itself. here is the link https://dash.plotly.com/persistence

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you passed persistence to the layout itself?

Comment: row1 = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Input(id="ad_account_id",
                      type="text",
                      placeholder="Account ID",
                      style={'width': '300px'}, persistence=True,
                      persistence_type='memory'),
        ], style={'margin-top': 20, 'margin-left': -250, 'display': 'table-cell', 'verticalAlign': 'middle'})])])     @Kay

Comment: @MishD If I understand the code correctly, you are trying to cache the `dbc.Input` component while you mentioned the layout `html.Div` component was cached?