# Dash App: Prevent Refreshing Page in Multi-Page App

Tags: plotly-dash, dashboard

How to prevent dash to refresh the page when switching between pages? For example, being at page1 having created a plot with a lot of items (dropdown menu, radiobuttons, etc.) and then leaving page1, going to page2, selecting other stuff, and if I then return to page1, the plot should be still there and the items should be still in the same state and not initialized again.

My code snippet of the NavBarLinks

[image]

Here is the URL linking to the corresponding layouts

[image]

Comment: The comment on this question tells you how it can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103773/dash-app-prevent-auto-refresh-when-switching-between-tabs

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, errors or any other text. Copy the original text here.

Answer (score 0):

A number of Dash components support this behavior natively via the [`persistence` property](https://dash.plotly.com/persistence). Alternative options include caching the state in a `Store` component (much more work, but more flexible and supports any component) or simply toggling visibly of pages as you navigate rather than re-rendering them.

Comment: Yes i have seen this persistence property but not all of the used items support that one. And you are right it would be an option to store them in a dcc.Store but don't you think this will be a lot of work if I have like 5 pages with about 15 components per page?:( I was hoping to find something like refresh=False but I think this is not existing in dash.